# How do I use 'paperclip' in Eclipse RadRails perspective?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, paperclip, aptana, radrails

I'm a newbie Ruby on Rails developer. I have installed the 'paperclip' gem by modifying the `config/environment.rb` file and adding the following:

```
config.gem 'paperclip', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org'
```

and then running `rake->gems->install` and `rake->gems->unpack`. Now, I would like to run the 'paperclip' generator however, it does not appear in the list of generators? The only example I found on how to use it was at: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/usage and it states that I can use the following command `script/generate paperclip User avatar`. How can I do that in the Eclipse IDE with RadRails perspective on?

Comment: Are you aware that you can run that from the command line? If you are on Windows, be sure to put ruby before script/generate.

Comment: OK - but I was hoping to find a way to do it within the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If RadRails perspective support the definition of [**builders** (see this article)](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html) on your Ruby on Rails projects, you could try and define your own builder calling paperclip, and use that builder in the order you want compared to other radrails existing builders.